# Responsive canvas element

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, canvas

I've created a responsive canvas but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to make a rectangle element inside the canvas also responsive. I need the rectangle to always be 100% of the canvas width, and the height needs too be a static 50px.

**Canvas Html**

```
<div id="newCanvas" role="main">
    <canvas id="respondCanvas" width="100" height="100">
        Please use a different browser
    </canvas>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#newCanvas {
display:block;
width:100%;
padding:50px 10%;
height:400px;
border:2px solid black;
background: #b8b894; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#b8b894, #ebebe0); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
background: -o-linear-gradient(#b8b894, #ebebe0); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#b8b894, #ebebe0); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
background: linear-gradient(#b8b894, #ebebe0); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    //Get the canvas & context
    var c = $('#respondCanvas');
    var ct = c.get(0).getContext('2d');
    var container = $(c).parent();

    //Run function when browser resizes
    $(window).resize( respondCanvas );

    function respondCanvas(){
        c.attr('width', $(container).width() ); //max width
        c.attr('height', $(container).height() ); //max height

        //Call a function to redraw other content (texts, images etc)
    }

    //Initial call
    respondCanvas();

    // Code I used to draw a road
    //function drawRoad() {
    //    ctx.beginPath();
    //    ctx.rect(x, y, w, h);
    //    ctx.closePath();
    //    ctx.fill();
    //};

    //drawRoad();

    //    var can = document.getElementById("newCanvas");
    //    var ctx = can.getContext("2d");
    //    ctx.moveTo(0, 75); //x-axis, y-axis
    //    ctx.lineTo(400, 75);
    //    ctx.strokeStyle = "grey";
    //    ctx.lineWidth = 20;
    //    ctx.stroke();

});
```

Demo
https://jsfiddle.net/ccvk3y5q/

References: 
http://www.garygarside.com/labs/responsive-canvas/

http://ameijer.nl/2011/08/resizable-html5-canvas/

[Make Html5 Canvas and Its contained image responsive across browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21083183/make-html5-canvas-and-its-contained-image-responsive-across-browsers)

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the desired results, you must redraw the canvas every few milliseconds and draw all the objects back on, so you must store the objects you wish to draw. You can then change variables in those stored objects (using event handlers, setTimeout(), etc.) to see the changes reflected in the canvas.

Example main loop:

```
function update(){
    ctx.beginPath;
    for(var i=0; i<rects.length;i++){
        ctx.drawRect(rects[i][0],rects[i][1],rects[i][2],rects[i][3]);
    }
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

To add rectangles (do so outside update()):

```
rects[easily rememberable number] = [x,y,width,height];
```

or

```
rects.push(x,y,width,height);
```

To edit height of rectangle:

```
rects[#][3] = 15;
```

Comment: Sounds about right as ive seen examples that use a similar concept. Unfortunately i dont know how to do it myself.

Comment: @Markus I would give you an example but it seems like I'm hitting a character limit of some sort, even in the answer itself.

Comment: Try updating my jsfiddle